# django how to know if new items are added to manytomanyfield

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, manytomanyfield

I am adding items to m2m using add() method but after adding items, how can I know whether any new items added or not, for better understanding have a look at my code

```
def new_or_get(self, request):
    user = request.user
    cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
    kart = get_or_none(Cart,id=cart_id)
    if kart:
        new_obj = False
        cart_obj = kart
        if user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
            try:
                cart = self.get(user=user)
                cart.products.add(*cart_obj.products.all())
                cart.messages = 'A'
                cart.save()
                cart_obj.delete()
                cart_obj = cart
            except:
                cart_obj.user = user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = kart
```

what I want is `cart.messages = 'A'` will only execute when new items added to cart, is there any builtin method for this, if not then how can I do this.

Comment: `if item in m2m_field` like, `if product in cart.products.all()`

Comment: @lemayzeur, I am trying to copy the products of session cart(variable name= cart_obj) to cart which is already associated with user (variable name=cart), it is possible that cart is having products already in it or the products  same as cart_obj  having , that why I asked any new item added. I hope now you understood what I meant to ask.

Comment: for more clarification I have edited the question, have a look.

Comment: Even though the new `cart` contains products already in session `cart_obj, django will never duplicate them, you can add all the products with no worries

Comment: @Lemayzeur, that's not an issue, as I asked, if any new item added then change message field to `cart.messages = 'A' ('A' means 'New items added to your cart')`

Comment: I can count the products before executing add method and after it, then execute  `cart.messages = 'A' ` `if(before<after)`, but I am here to ask is there any method to check update in m2m field ?

Comment: yes, you can proceed that way, the number of items before the change is less than the number of items after the change, you could do it by checking whether there's an object from cart_session that is not in new cart, but your method is faster I think